# How does server-to-server FTP transfer work in WinSCP GUI

Tags: ftp, winscp

Maybe it's quite straightforward, but am not aware how to find this. My requirement is to transfer data from source FTP server to destination FTP server.

To accomplish this I have installed WinSCP software on my local Windows machine. Before initiating any kind of transfer, I just wanted to verify, how actual transfer would look in the background. Is it from the source to local OS copy and then an upload to the destination? Or direct source to destination after process orchestrate? Really need some path/documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct FTP to FTP transfer is called [FXP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol). That feature is disabled on most FTP servers.

WinSCP does not even support it, as it's pointless to implement something that virtually no server allows.

Theres' WinSCP FAQ covering this topic: [Can I transfer files between two remote servers with WinSCP?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_fxp)

So it's Server 1 -> Local -> Server 2.

---

You might be able to do direct transfers, if you have another access to one (or both) of the servers. Particularly a shell access.