# Transfer files from one remote server to another remote server in WinSCP

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, ssh-tunnel, winscp

I want to transfer some files from one remote server to another remote server. The issue is these servers are accessible to be by doing hop from a jump server.

I am able to get into these servers using a hop from Jump Server (10.9.6.54).
Then I do a `sudo su - xyz` and access directory files at `/app/myDir` for server 10.0.4.11.
I want to transfer directory files at `/app/myDir` from  Dev server 10.1.2.34 to 4 other servers with below IPs.

```
10.3.8.0
10.3.7.1
10.3.2.8 
10.3.0.2
```

How can I do this by WinSCP as I have do a hop from JumpServer (10.9.6.54) to any other servers.

Comment: What do you imagine under *"Transfer files from server to another server"*. In WinSCP you can transfer files between two remote servers. But it will download and reupload the files. Is that ok? See for example [How does server-to-server FTP transfer work in WinSCP GUI](https://superuser.com/q/1618744/213663).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am trying to transfer file from one remote server to another remote server. Both remote servers are accessible by tunneling through another jump server.

Comment: I know that. That's not what I have asked.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sorry I did not get the question. I just wanted to know if this is possible via Winscp. I know that by putty I can do a ssh to jump server and then ssh to the destination server. Is this possible via Winscp?

Comment: Have you tried to use the WinSCP feature "Connect through SSH tunnel" (Advanced -> Connection -> Tunnel)?

Comment: *"if this is possible"* – But WHAT? The connection through the jump server? Yes, as @robert answered. Or the transfer between two remote servers? Yes, but... See the linked question. The problem is that you are asking two different questions in one post.

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP can both:

- [Connect a session via an SSH jump server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel).
- [Transfer files between two sessions](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_fxp) (via a local temporary copy).